# How to skip the docstring using regex

Tags: python

I'm trying to insert some import lines into a python source file, but i would ideally like to place them right after the initial docstring. Let's say I load the file into the lines variable like this:

```
lines = open('filename.py').readlines()
```

How to find the line number, where the docstring ends?

Comment: Note that PEP8 recommends to put imports before docstrings.

Comment: No, PEP8 doesn't recommend that, and it would in fact make the docstrings not docstrings. Docstrings are only docstrings when they are the first expression in a module, class or function. PEP8 says imports have to come immediately after comments and docstrings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the standard docstring format, you can do something like this:

```
count = 0
for line in lines:
    if line.startswith ('"""'):
        count += 1
        if count < 3:
            # Before or during end of the docstring
            continue
    # Line is after docstring
```

Might need some adaptation for files with no docstrings, but if your files are formatted consistently it should be easy enough.

Comment: Don't forget that a docstring is not just a triple-quoted string literal. A docstring is *any* string literal that is the first expression in a module, class or function. It can use """, ''', ", ', or even r""", r''', r', r", u""", u''', u", u', ur""", ur''', ur" or ur' for the opening quotes.

Comment: That's what I mean by "standard docstring format" -- PEP 8 says to use triple-string literals.

Comment: There are some tricky variants even with "standard" docstrings.  See PEP257's commends on unicode and raw string docstrings. There's also the common case of the one-liner, or where the """ isn't at the start of a line. Also consider docstrings with embedded """ strings using escaping (\""")

Answer (score 11):

Rather than using a regex, or relying on specific formatting you could use python's tokenize module.

```
import tokenize
f=open(filename)
insert_index = None
for tok, text, (srow, scol), (erow,ecol), l in tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline):
    if tok == tokenize.COMMENT:
        continue
    elif tok == tokenize.STRING:
        insert_index = erow, ecol
        break
    else:
        break # No docstring found
```

This way you can even handle pathological cases like:

```
# Comment
# """Not the real docstring"""
' this is the module\'s \
docstring, containing:\
""" and having code on the same line following it:'; this_is_code=42
```

excactly as python would handle them.

Answer (score 0):

This is a function based on Brian's brilliant answer you can use to split a file into docstring and code:

```
def split_docstring_and_code(infile):

    import tokenize
    insert_index = None
    f = open(infile)
    for tok, text, (srow, scol), (erow,ecol), l in tokenize.generate_tokens(f.readline):
        if tok == tokenize.COMMENT:
            continue
        elif tok == tokenize.STRING:
            insert_index = erow, ecol
            break
        else:
            break # No docstring found

    lines = open(infile).readlines()
    if insert_index is not None:
        erow = insert_index[0]
        return "".join(lines[:erow]), "".join(lines[erow:])
    else:
        return "", "".join(lines)
```

It assumes that the line that ends the docstring does not contain additional code past the closing delimiter of the string.